# Industry removal icon is misplaced

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs

While searching jobs and applying filters, I noticed this:

> [image]

This happens after I apply Industry filter, then come back to it. (When adding it's fine.)

The removal icon is still clickable and working, just misplaced.

Browser: Chrome 54, Windows 7.

Comment: There's a similar bug on http://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current in the 'Developer types' field.